# NoMethodError in Admin#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, agile, nomethoderror

I'm a newbie having an issue with Agile Web Development with Rails 2nd. Ruby verison 1.8.6. The issue started when the book instructed me to put scaffold product in the admin_controller.rb. I removed the line and now i'm getting the following error message.

NoMethodError in Admin#index 
Showing admin/index.html.erb where line #10 raised:

You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.each

Extracted source (around line #10):

```
7:     <th>Image url</th>
8:   </tr>
9: 
10: <% for product in @product %>
11:   <tr>
12:     <td><%=h product.title %></td>
13:     <td><%=h product.description %></td>
```

RAILS_ROOT: C:/InstantRails-2.0-win/rails_apps/depot

Here's the controller information:admin_controller
class AdminController < ApplicationController
end

Here's the view information: Views\admin\index.html.erb

## Listing products

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Image url</th>
  </tr>

<% for product in @product %>
  <tr>
     <td><%=h product.title %></td>
    <td><%=h product.description %></td>
    <td><%=h product.image_url %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', product %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(product) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', product, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method          => :delete %></td>
      </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New product', new_product_path %>
```

Here's the models information: Models\product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
end

Any advise?

Comment: What does the controller for Admin look like? Does it have an index action? Are you setting `@product` within it?

Comment: The admin controller was empty. The book suggested scaffold :product which gave me a error message. Here's the current controller from someone's suggestion. class AdminController < ApplicationController
def index
 @products = Product.all
end

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like @products isn't being set in your controller and you also have a possible typo in the view:

in views\admin\index.html.erb, change:

```
 <% for product in @product %>
```

to:

```
 <% for product in @products %>
```

and ensure your controller has:

admin_controller.rb

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController 

  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Here's the new error message. NoMethodError in AdminController#index 
undefined method `all' for #<Class:0x36aa614>
RAILS_ROOT: C:/InstantRails-2.0-win/rails_apps/depot

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace 
C:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.0.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:1532:in `method_missing'
app/controllers/admin_controller.rb:3:in `index'

Comment: Well, that's something entirely different, and I fear the path this is going to take.  Are you are sure you have a Product model? app/models/product.rb ?

Comment: yes but at the moment it's empty. class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
end

Comment: It doesn't need anything in there at this point as long as there's a table in the db named "products".  Please ensure that exists too.

Comment: info from migrate 001_create_products.rb class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.column :title,       :string
      t.column :description, :text
      t.column :image_url,   :string
    end
  end
  def self.down
    drop_table :products
  end
end

Comment: Yes, that's the migration that would create the table.  Have you run this migration (rake db:migrate)?  Does the table exist in the database itself?

Comment: I'm not sure how to confirm if the table exist in the database. However after typing rake db:migrate i get the following page Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage.

Comment: @yatta20 - This thread is going well beyond the scope of your original problem and should not continue in these comments. I'd recommend continuing to read your book as it surely covers how to migrate a database and use the rails console as well. Good luck.